# How to retrieve data from a model "function" with model.objects.values()?

Tags: django, django-models

this is my model

```
class ArtWork(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
   desc = models.TextField(max_length=100)
   image = models.ImageField(upload_to=get_post_filename, null=True, blank=True)
   category = models.ForeignKey('Category', null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
   album = models.OneToOneField('PostImages', related_name='model', 
                                        blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
   # identifier
   private_unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)
   public_unique_id = models.CharField(max_length=200, blank=True, unique=True, default=uuid.uuid4)


   def __str__(self):
       return self.title

   def get_ratings(self):
       like = Vote.objects.filter(artwork=self, like=True, nope=False).count()
       nope = Vote.objects.filter(artwork=self, nope=True, like=False).count()

       return like, nope
```

I'd like to get the ArtWork model function "get_ratings" in views with "values" filter

in views.py

```
if request.is_ajax():
    posts = ArtWork.objects.filter(active=True)
    data = serializers.serialize("json", posts, fields=('image', 'title', 'desc','get_ratings'))
    return JsonResponse(data, content_type='application/json', safe=False)

posts = ArtWork.objects.filter(active=True).only('get_ratings').values('image', 'title', 'desc',)
return render(request, 'Home.html', {'posts': posts[:3]})
```

what I want to do is basically return for ajax request in views a list of objects including the results of the function

any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: This is one of the (very) many reasons *not* to use `.values()`: https://www.django-antipatterns.com/antipattern/over-use-of-values.html

Comment: So what would you suggest for me to use?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to create new Artwork object, I'd do it like this:

```
class ArtWork(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=40)
    ...

    @classmethod
    def get_ratings(cls, field1):
       like = Vote.objects.filter(artwork=self, like=True, nope=False).count()
       nope = Vote.objects.filter(artwork=self, nope=True, like=False).count()
       return like, nope
```

then, import it in your view:

```
from <app_name>.models import ArtWork
.....
ArtWork.get_rating()
```

This works for me, hope this help you too.

Comment: I updated my question to explain more my problem

Answer (score 0):

You should use custom managers to apply methods to QuerySets.

```
class ArtWorkManager(models.Manager):
def get_ratings(self):
   like = Vote.objects.filter(artwork=self, like=True, nope=False).count()
   nope = Vote.objects.filter(artwork=self, nope=True, like=False).count()

   return like, nope
```

also, you should add the below line to Artwork model:

```
objects = ArtWorkManager()
```

Check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/managers/#custom-managers) link for custom managers.

Comment: that's ok if you wanna create a new object instance for it, what I want to do is basically return for ajax request in views a list of objects including the results of the function

Comment: i'm gonna add it to my question

Comment: @YankiSegal okay, I updated my answer. Check it again. I hope it helps.